# Google::Voice perl module not working now

Tags: perl, cookies, module, voice

I was using Google::Voice perl module (version 0.03) to automatically login to google voice
and send sms. So far it was working fine. From past say, 2 weeks it stopped working.

The related modules and their versions are given below.

IO::Socket::SSL -v 1.44
Mojolicious -v 1.98
Net::SSLeay -v 1.36

I could see that when try to login to google voice, now it shows the error "Your browser's cookie functionality is turned off. Please turn it on."

Could anybody help me on this issue ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Google modified their markup; it happens from time to time.

I'm sure you've already discovered that the latest version in CPAN works as expected.  In the future, submit an issue at https://github.com/tempire/perl-google-voice to notify the author of the problem.  In this case, another user informed the author (me!) and found what Google had changed, so I was able to fix it quickly.

The source is fairly simple to understand; if it happens again, feel free to look into the code on github and see what you can do.